# Do I have to run rake assets:clean before rake assets:precompile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I deploy code to my production server using git. This might include changes to JS and CSS files.

Do I have to run `rake assets:clean` at all before I run `rake assets:precompile`? I'm worried that not cleaning the previous precompiled assets might have side effects.

This is a little silly, but my google-fu didn't find any answers. My AWS instance runs `rake assets:clean` pretty slowly and I'm wondering if it's needed at all.

Also, can I replace the clean command with a simple `rm -r public/assets`?

Comment: If used in Rubymine, must it be run in rubymine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No you do not need to run rake assets:clean before, just running rake assets:precompile will recompile your assets. It will recreate your cache busting digest and manifest.yml (which contains key/value mappings that match each asset name to its MD5 cache-busted name)

and yes you can just run rm -r public/assets

Comment: To be thorough, there won't be any legacy files from the last precompile left in the public/assets directory if you dont clean?

Comment: I believe the assets folder will only consist of what was precompiled. You can double check if deleted assets still show up but they should not be listed in the manifest.yml which maps everything together

Comment: Kyle, this is what I'm seeing as well. 

When I run rake assets:clean it doesn't remove the previous version of my compiled CSS files. I'm wondering if maybe it keeps the previous version around on purpose?

Comment: Wes, Are you precompiling for Development or Production? Did you try "rm -r public/assets"?

Comment: I got this error due to not cleaning before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063613/rake-aborted-argumenterror-same-file