# How can one clean old Rails assets when they are being precompiled locally and added to repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I use Capistrano for deploying my Rails 4 app. Precompiling assets on the server is very slow so I manually precompile it in development using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and add it to my git repo.

The problem I am facing is that the `assets:precompile` task does not remove the old assets. So, I have multiple copies of `application-<manifest code>.css` and `application-<manifest-code>.js` in my public assets.

Capistrano has `deploy:assets:clean_expired` task for this though I am not sure how can I replicate it in my case. I have seen other approaches which use capistrano task to precompile assets and rsync them up. This link - http://keighl.com/post/fast-rails-assets-precompile-capistrano/ - has an approach for Rails 3 using the `turbo-sprockets-rails3` gem.

There are similar questions here - [Do I have to run rake assets:clean before rake assets:precompile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103347/do-i-have-to-run-rake-assetsclean-before-rake-assetsprecompile) and [Confusion about rake assets:clean / cleanup on the asset pipeline in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335803/confusion-about-rake-assetsclean-cleanup-on-the-asset-pipeline-in-rails?rq=1)

How can I adapt it for Rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

This is working well for me now - https://gist.github.com/mishrarohit/7802260 It uses git revision history to check if any changes have been made to assets. It will be better if we can use the manifest for this.